# How to filter key and value using jq filter in bash

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

After running the following command

`aws ec2 describe-tags   --filter "Name=resource-id,Values=i-8dh7435490fjksfd"`

I have the following JSON output

```
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435490fjksfd", 
            "Value": "production", 
            "Key": "Environment"
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435490fjksfd", 
            "Value": "webserver", 
            "Key": "Application"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i get the following output using jq filter

Application : webserver

Comment: You don't need `jq`. Use `--query` option of CLI. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution without using `jq`

```
aws ec2 describe-tags   --filter "Name=resource-id,Values=i-8dh7435490fjksfd" --query 'Tags[?Key==`Application`].Value[]' --output text
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.Tags[]
| select(.Key == "Application")
| "\(.Key) : \(.Value)"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get it in this way with using jq. Putting parentheses around the key means it will be evaluated as an expression.

```
cat example.json | jq '.[] | {(.[].Key): (.[].Value)}'
```

Output:

```
{
  "Environment": "production"
}
{
  "Environment": "webserver"
}
{
  "Application": "production"
}
{
  "Application": "webserver"
}
```

Ref: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/